# How to highlight all links containing keywords from array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm searching a web page for keywords from an array. This code works by replacing text with a  tag which highlights the text, but when it finds keywords that are links then it breaks them because it puts a `<span>` tag within the `<a>` tag.

I tried to refer to the parent element by changing $this.html() to $this.parent.html() but this didn't work. Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uzfsjqyr/1/

I'd appreciate some help, please?

```js
var regex = /(Apples|oranges)/g;
$('*').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    if (regex.test(text)) {
        $this.html(
            $this.html().replace(regex, '</a><span style="background: #fa7373;">$1</span>')
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: So far none of the answers provided are working, they are just variants that are causing the same or similar problem. It might just be a good bet to go with an existing plugin even though it might seem like overkill. Mark.js is available with and without jquery

Comment: Check once more if the tag contains a src or href, for example: `var excluded = /(src|href)([\w\W]+?)>/g; if (excluded.test(text)) === false) { ... }` . If false then do not hilite the string/tag.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be selecting all `p` and `a` tags in the `body` instead of using `*` which will even select the `script` tag itself. Also, remove the `</a>` that is closing any anchor tag. To not modify the HTML of anchor tags, you can check that the current element has no children before replacing.

```js
var regex = /(apples|oranges)/g;

$('body a, body p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    if (text.match(regex) && $this.children().length===0) {
        $this.html(
            $this.html().replace(regex, '<span style="background: #fa7373;">$1</span>')
        );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
I bought some apples.
</p>

<p>
<a href="oranges.html">I bought some oranges.</a>
</p>

<p>
I bought some pears.
</p>
```

Comment: This modifies the HREF, so its breaking the URL of the link.

Comment: Thank you @hev1 , it works perfectly. If anyone needs it, you can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/rgyeuafw/

Comment: @TimB No problem.

Comment: @hev1 , I have a follow up question, not sure if I should ask here or start a new thread? In the web page, each line is contained within a <div> tag and has other information about each individual product. E.g. <div><p>I bought some apples</p><p>Apples are £2 per kg</p></div>. I want to keep highlighting the matched word as you've shown me, but I also want to make all of the text within the <div> tag to have a light grey font colour so I can easily ignore that particular product, when scanning down the page. How can I do this?

Comment: @TimB It's probably best to ask a new question. I unfortunately do not have time right now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `</a>` from your code. This `</a>` is closing any anchor tag.

```
var regex = /(apples|oranges)/g;

$('*').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    if (regex.test(text)) {
        $this.html(
            $this.html().replace(regex, '<mark>$1</mark>')
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: This modifies the HREF, so it might not look like it breaks the link but its breaking the URL of the link.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @nicolae-cas%c3%aer . It does break the link, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/t8kwz1rx/